# Where to put utility classes in PHP MVC?

Tags: design-patterns, php, mvc

I am creating a PHP project using the MVC pattern.
You can see the directory structure below.

My question: where can I put utility classes like Email and Date?

Project directory structure:

```
- app/
   - Models/
   - Controllers/
   - Views/
- vendor/
- composer.json
- composer.lcok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any other utility class/helper function/convenience whatever, where to put it depends on who's using it. If only M uses it, then maybe it belongs in the Model folder. If your M, V and C are all using Dates, then maybe Date belongs in a separate folder from all three. You don't have to put every piece of code in one of those three folders.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to have a separate directory like "Services" or "Utilities". Then your MVC layers can use these functionalities.

Project directory structure:

```
- app/
   - Models/
   - Controllers/
   - Views/
   - Services/
      - Mail/Mailer.php
      - Mail/MailTrap.php
      - Mail/AmazonSES.php
      - Sms/Provider.php
      - Auth/OtpProviider.php
- vendor/
- composer.json
- composer.lcok
```